# adding new drive to zfs raidz

Tags: hard-drive, raid, zfs

i have this raid set up:

```
root@zen:/dev# zpool status zfs-raid
  pool: zfs-raid
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported and requested features are not enabled on the pool.
    The pool can still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
    the features. See zpool-features(7) for details.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 12:38:49 with 0 errors on Sun Oct  9 13:02:51 2022
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zfs-raid    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

i want to 'grow' this raidz array with some new disks (sdd and sde)

i have tried `zpool attach zfs-raid /dev/sdc /dev/sdd` but that gives and error: `cannot attach /dev/sdd to /dev/sdc: can only attach to mirrors and top-level disks`

i have also tried:

```
root@zen:/dev# zpool add zfs-raid /dev/sdd
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
mismatched replication level: pool uses raidz and new vdev is disk
```

Comment: Are the new disks the same size as the ones currently in the pool? 

Comment: yes they are i bought exactly the same model of disks as before. i decided to back up the data, nuke the pool and start again.  that is working and only has about a day to copy left ! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

*TLDR:* You cannot add devices to a RAIDZ… yet (edited bellow) !

This is an old limitation as [mentioned by *Dan Naumov* in 2009](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-fs/2009-June/006329.html)

> To reiterate, you cant just add a single disk drive to a raidz1 or
> raidz2 pool. This is a known limitation (you can check with SUN ZFS
> docs). If you have an existing raidz and you MUST increase that
> particular pool's storage capabilities, you have 3 options:
>
> 1. Add a raidz of the same configuration to the pool (think 3 disk
>    raidz + 3 disk raidz or 5 + 5, for example)
> 2. Replace each (and every) disk in your raidz pool one by one,
>    letting it resilver after inserting each upgraded disk
> 3. Backup your data, destroy your pool and create a new raidz pool
>    with a bigger amount of disks.

But [current docs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/zpool.8.html) still mention it:

> `zpool attach [-f]  [-o property=value] pool device new_device`
>
> Attaches new_device to an existing zpool device. The existing device cannot be part of a  raidz  configuration.  If device is not currently part of a mirrored configuration, device automatically transforms into a two-way mirror of  device  and  new_device. If device  is  part of a two-way mirror, attaching new_device creates a three-way mirror, and so on. In either case, new_device begins to resilver immediately.

---

*November 2023 edit :* Hey Marty, we received news from the future!

RAIDZ extension is announced to be [released in ZFS 2.3](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/15022#issuecomment-1802428899). It was a long run issue (~6 years), details in [OpenZFS Developer Summit 2023](https://openzfs.org/wiki/OpenZFS_Developer_Summit_2023) :

- [the talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqyNHyq0LYM&list=PLaUVvul17xSegbzdTT2Mo-QCDzEn5Z3XC&index=3&pp=iAQB)
- [the slides](https://openzfs.org/w/images/5/5e/RAIDZ_Expansion_2023.pdf)

Comment: thanks - that is what i thought - looks like it has been a feature that has been asked for and is in development but not released yet.  I just decided to nuke the pool and restore from backup.

Comment: What does 2. accomplish? What do I put on the new drives and what will be the result after all drives have been "upgraded" and resilvered?

Comment: Good point @problemofficer-n.f.Monica. In my thoughts, I'll do the step 2 and after I'll set [`autoexpand=on`](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zpoolprops.7.html#autoexpand) to avoid a backup restauration